# What Type of GlobalKey is needed for a TextFormField?

Tags: flutter

Usually key of a `Widget` is `var key = GlobalKey<WidgetState>` but `TextFormFieldState` is private. Since I have only one text form, I am avoiding to wrap it in `Form`. Can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GlobalKey<FormFieldState>()`